# Получить атрибут элемента на который нажали

Tags: html, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть таблица:

```
<tr class="tablesorter-headerRow" onclick="sortTable();">
    <!--<td data-column="0" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner"><input type = "checkbox" name = "lol"></input><i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>!-->
    <td data-column="0" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">№<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="1" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc primary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Cмс<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="2" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc secondary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Номеров<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="3" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc tertiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Время создания<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="4" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc fourtiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Периодичность<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="5" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc fivetiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Имя отправителя<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="6" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc sixtiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Сообщение<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="7" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc seventiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Начало отправки<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="8" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc eight" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Окончание отправки<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="9" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc nine" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Действие<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
</tr>
```

Нужно получить атрибут `data-column` столбца, на который нажали. Делаю так:

```
function sortTable()
{
    var attr = $(this).attr("data-column");
    alert(attr);
}
```

Выводит `undefined`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй подписку на всплытие:

```js
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
  console.log($(this).data("column"));
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
    <td data-column="0" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">№<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="1" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc primary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Cмс<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="2" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc secondary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Номеров<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="3" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc tertiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Время создания<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="4" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc fourtiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Периодичность<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="5" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc fivetiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Имя отправителя<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="6" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc sixtiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Сообщение<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="7" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc seventiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Начало отправки<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="8" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc eight" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Окончание отправки<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="9" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc nine" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Действие<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а он точно атрибута значение берет?
делаю `<td data-column="255" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc primary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Cмс<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>`
а он выдает 1

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужен атрибут ячейки, поэтому обрабатываем событие ячейки. Тогда `$(this)` укажет на нажатую ячейку.

```js
$('td').click( function() {
  var attr = $(this).data("column");
  alert(attr);
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
    <td data-column="0" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">№<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="1" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc primary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Cмс<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="2" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc secondary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Номеров<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="3" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc tertiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Время создания<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="4" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc fourtiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Периодичность<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="5" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc fivetiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Имя отправителя<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="6" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc sixtiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Сообщение<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="7" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc seventiary" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Начало отправки<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="8" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc eight" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Окончание отправки<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
    <td data-column="9" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc nine" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Действие<i class="tablesorter-icon tablesorter-icon"></i></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. Для атрибутов `data-*` у jQuery есть [метод `.data()`](http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=78). Кстати, он сам приводит значения этих атрибутов к типам данных Javascript.
3. Консоль удобнее алертов. Она умеет [подставлять значения в форматную строку](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114483/), показывает свою историю и не заставляет жать <kbd>OK</kbd> по каждому случаю.

```js
var total = 0;

$('table').click( function() {
  console.log( 'table %s', $(this).data("table") );
})

$('tr').click( function() {
  console.log( 'row %s', $(this).data("row") );
})

$('td').click( function() {
  var column = $(this).data("column");
  total += column;
  console.log( 'column %s, total %s', column, total );
})
```

```css
td { padding: 3px 9px; }

table:hover { background: #ccc; }
tr:hover    { background: #999; }
td:hover    { background: #333; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<table data-table="one">
  <tr data-row="first">
    <td data-column="1">1</td>
    <td data-column="2">2</td>
    <td data-column="3">3</td>
    <td data-column="4">4</td>
    <td data-column="5">5</td>
    <td data-column="6">6</td>
    <td data-column="7">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="second">
    <td data-column="1">1</td>
    <td data-column="2">2</td>
    <td data-column="3">3</td>
    <td data-column="4">4</td>
    <td data-column="5">5</td>
    <td data-column="6">6</td>
    <td data-column="7">7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table data-table="two">
  <tr data-row="first">
    <td data-column="1">1</td>
    <td data-column="2">2</td>
    <td data-column="3">3</td>
    <td data-column="4">4</td>
    <td data-column="5">5</td>
    <td data-column="6">6</td>
    <td data-column="7">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="second">
    <td data-column="1">1</td>
    <td data-column="2">2</td>
    <td data-column="3">3</td>
    <td data-column="4">4</td>
    <td data-column="5">5</td>
    <td data-column="6">6</td>
    <td data-column="7">7</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _"поэтому обрабатываем событие ячейки"_ - брррррр.. Не, так не надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy Добавьте, пожалуйста, пару слов, почему и как лучше?

Comment: Я вроде в ответе написал. А лучше потому что там обработчик получается только один и он сможет работать с динамически добавляемыми строками без дополнительных усилий.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо. Вот ещё [об отличиях между `.click()` и `.on()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/6263942/) (на английском).

Comment: Вообще-то click - это просто обёртка над on.